# rlwrap hangs jobs while running at the background

Tags: linux, bash, background, tcl, rlwrap

I have a problem with rlwrap (see the man page [here](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/rlwrap.html)). Consider this situation: `empty.tcl` is an empty file. At bash this line

`tclsh empty.tcl &`

runs the job in the background and exits it, so i get this prompt

`[1]+  Done                    tclsh empty.tcl`.

While this line

`rlwrap tclsh empty.tcl &`

runs the job in the background and doesn't exit it, so i get this prompt

`[1]+  Stopped                 rlwrap tclsh empty.tcl`.

The corresponding job hangs at the background. My question is how to make it exit the job rather then hang?

rlwrap is a Linux utility command which *runs the specified command, intercepting user input in order to provide readline’s line editing, persistent history and completion*. As it is mentioned there, the main property of rlwrap is *you shouldn’t notice any difference between command and rlwrap command*, however, as it is described above, this property doesn't hold.

Maybe one can suggest an alternative for rlwrap which functions as expected?

Comment: Have you already tried the parameters `-a` and `-N`?

Comment: @tangens Yes. `rlwrap tclsh -a empty.tcl &`, `rlwrap tclsh -N empty.tcl &`, `rlwrap tclsh -a -N empty.tcl &` all behave like `rlwrap tclsh empty.tcl &` in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't do this and have it work. The problem (from your perspective) is that if you pass a script file argument to `tclsh`, it will execute it and then exit. Either use `rlwrap tclsh` with no further arguments (so it works in interactive mode) or use a script that emulates Tcl's interactive REPL. That's not too hard to write:

```
fconfigure stdout -buffering none
set command ""
puts -nonewline "% "
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    append command $line "\n"
    if {[info complete $command]} {
        # Got a complete command; evaluate and catch result
        if {[catch $command msg]} {
            puts "error: $msg"
        } elseif {$msg ne ""} {
            puts $msg
        }
        set command ""
        puts -nonewline "% "
    }
}
```

OK, you could tweak it a bit more, but it shows how to do it. Stick it at the end of your *real* script and `rlwrap` should cope just fine with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue in bash,  `rlwrap bash ./t.sh &`  , solved that by escaping &,  `rlwrap bash ./t.sh \&` .

That is not good here, it will pass & as an input param.

Comment: Yes, you wanted `&` to refer to `bash`, and i want `&` to refer to `rlwrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Any command that is run in the background will get a SIGTTY as soon as it tries to  read from stdin (standard input) (try `tclsh &`). `rlwrap` will always read from stdin, even when the rlwrapped command doesn't. Strictly speaking, the original poster is right in saying that this breaks rlwrap's purported transparency

Is this a serious problem? I don't think so - `rlwrap` is of course only useful for commands that read from stdin anyway, and there is no point in running those commands in the background, with or without rlwrap

Hans Lub (rlwrap author)